# Idea doesn't see imports

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, intellij-idea

I try to work with angular2 in Idea IDE.

My code valid(I tried  compile and execute it), but ide shows this:
[image]

Is there way to configure Idea  to hide this erros?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have missed two things: mentioning what you want to import from 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap', and the 'from' keyword.

Change this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'
```

to this:

```
import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'
```

or, it might work for you this way:

```
import * as switchMap from 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'
```

Comment: but my imports coorect